# Overlay transparent video with MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a video in .webm format with a transparent background(clip2) and a normal mp4 video(clip1). I want to overlay clip2 video on clip1 video, but when I do that, the transparent feature in the background of clip2 disappears and a red beam of light comes on.

Here is my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip
clip1 = VideoFileClip("test.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("transparent.webm")
clip2 = clip2.resize(0.25)

video = CompositeVideoClip([clip1,
                            clip2.set_position(("right","bottom"))])

video.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

I have tried to change the output format with libvpx-vp9 but it doesn't seems to work either

Answer (score 0):

Does you webm video has alpha channel? If no recreate your video with alpha channel. If yes may be you should try using mov format, I have tried and it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).